# Identify the Alexa Dot Versus Show - Is a display present?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

We are looking for a function or code to quickly identify if Lambda code is running on an Alexa Dot/Echo or a Show/Spot. More than the device ID, we want the device type.  Based on the device capability, display or no display, the code will provide different types of content. We are hoping not to include a "device registration" feature. We are building a health-related Skill, which will also be for seniors, so we want to include visual interactions if a display is present, in the simplest possible fashion. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to examine the request and determine if a display is present, such as context.System.device.supportedInterfaces, I think it is. Under there you can look for Display, so you are not looking so much for a particular model, rather for specific functionality, such as a display.